# Complex PFQuery

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

I'm working on an app where users can follow each other. On the app there is a leaderboard that will show the users sorted by popularity and date. Popularity is how many people followed each user recently.

This will be a list of 10 people

I have a PFObject called follow. This has a relationship to the person and the date created.

I'm a little perplexed how I can create a query that sorts the follow object by date. For example, I need to sort who had the most followers today. If there is one, the next person would need to be the person with the most new followers yesterday. After that it may be the person who had the most votes last week. And so on...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read the part called Query Constraints here: https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries

It describes how to sort queries by multiple criteria.

If that doesn't quite work, you could always store the objects in arrays and find your highest counts that way.